# Capybara cannot see variable set by controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

In my `index`-**controller**, I have this code:

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

The relevant part of the **view** looks like this:

```
<% for c in @categories %>
  <div id="location_radio">
     <%= radio_button_tag "category", c.id %><%= c.name %>
  </div>
<% end -%>
```

which is rendered like this in the **browser**:

```
<input checked="checked" id="category_1" name="category" type="radio" value="1">
```

And my **spec** looks like this:

```
describe "Find nearby location" do
  it 'finds a location nearby the submitted address' do

    @location = create(:location) 

    visit index_path
    fill_in "search", :with => "Stortinget, Oslo"
    choose "category_1"
    click_button "Find Location!"
  end
end
```

Now. The problem is that when I try and print the page body using `puts page.body`, I can see that the radio-button elements are not present. This leads me to believe that the `@categories`-variable which is generated by the controller is never created.

**TL;DR**: If a user `visit`'s a page with Capybara, will the action for the respective view be ran and thus variables made visible to the view?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Capybara interacts with your running server using the same interface that it presents to the user. When you visit a page in Capybara the same code runs as would run if you visited in your browser. If your view doesn't see a variable that it should, it's because it's not being set in the action.

If the view does see the variable, but *Capybara* doesn't see the *result* of the variable, it might be a bug in the page, or a mistake in how you're looking for it on the page, or that the test hasn't done whatever is necessary for it to appear.

Comment: Sorry, been neck deep in exams. The variable was being properly set in the action. The problem proved to be that all dynamically loaded DOM-elements are not instantly available to Capybara. I had to do a `find("#element_id").click_link "Linkname"` in order to make Capybara wait for it to load.

Comment: Glad the problem is solved. For future readers, you should edit your question to add the clue that you're using a Javascript driver, answer your own question and accept that.